# Other than Fairy-Max, is there a variant [fairy] chess engine that is compatible with XBoard?

Tags: engines, software, chess-variants, linux

Fairy-Max (which ships with the XBoard package) can play variant chess. Is there any other XBoard-compatible engine that also plays variant chess (and runs on Linux or *BSD)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have idea what the question is about. Can you rephrase? Do you mean if fairymax can play anything other than the standard chess?

Comment: No, I was asking about an alternative to Fairymax.

Comment: This is easy. Xboard supports every chess engine that uses its protocol. Crafty can be used on xboard.

Comment: But I am only interested by chess variant engine. Crafty, as I know, only support standard chess. I’m wrong?

Comment: Now I understand what you're actually asking. I'll edit your answer. Please take a little more attention to your wording in the question next time.

Comment: “[fairy chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess)” is the standard name used by chess gamer to talk about a __kind__ of chess variant. I use the correct words.

Answer (score 7):

The **[XBoard Alien GUI](http://hgm.nubati.net/alien.html)** is reputedly better suited to playing chess variants than the standard XBoard is, but that's just an observation. There are many engines that play only a few variants.
     Here's a list of engines (other than Fairy-Max) that have been noted as playing a large selection of variants and working with XBoard (Linux environment being implicit):

- **[ChessV](http://samiam.org/chessv/)** (*plays over 50 variants*)
- **[Nebiyu Alien](https://sites.google.com/site/dshawul/)** (*a score of variants tested in homepage; many additional [user defined] .ini files available as a [collective package](http://www.solidfiles.com/d/67f321a0a9/) or [individually](http://immortalchess.net/forum/showthread.php?t=12308)*)
- **[Pulsar](http://www.lanternchess.com/pulsar/)**
- **[Sjaak II](http://www.eglebbk.dds.nl/program/chess-)** (*Glebbeek's, not de Man's*)
- **[SMIRF](http://www.chessbox.de/chess/SMIRF.html)**

Answer (score 0):

add [Fairy Stockfish](https://github.com/ianfab/Fairy-Stockfish/releases/tag/fairy_sf_14) to that list... a recent development